# Generating data with a loop to use the predict function in R

Tags: r, loops, predict

I've built a model with numeric and factor variables to predict sales based on advertising with weekly data from 2017 to 2019 and I am trying to run a code that will predict the monthly sales for 2020, for each combination of variables.

For that, I need to input the right factor variables, and I was wondering what would be the best way to go about it, here is what my regression looks like:

```
regads2 = lm(dolsales~flavour+brand+packaging+month+organization+manufacturer+region+displaydummie+addummie+maddummie+laddummie+discount5to10+discount10to15
            +discount15to20+discount20to25+discount25to30+discount30to35+discount35to40+discount40to45+discount45to50+
              discount50to55+discount55to60+discount60to65+discount65to70+discount70to75, na.action = na.exclude,data = df)
```

Each of the factor variables have many levels (from 5 to 30), while "discount" variables are dummies. I tried to write a loop that would generate the data based on the levels of variables and store them but I haven't been able to fully get there and I am finding myself a little stuck. Here is what I wrote so far (it is working for one variable, but not for many)

```
input <- matrix(ncol= 1, nrow = nlevels(region))
for(i in c(0:nlevels(region))) {
    working[i,] <- levels(region)[i]
     }
input
```

I imagine there is a simpler way to go about it.

Thanks so much, I've been stuck on that for a good week now.

Comment: It seems your variables have high correlation, maybe regression is not the best way to model it?

Comment: Also, you don't have to save `region` to another variable, just create a `dataframe` with column name `region` as prediction data.